# using Transform.lookat() based on a different vector representing forward.

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In unity3D I am trying to orientate a capsule so that the y axis points at another game object. Basically I'm trying to use the vector3.up instead of the vector3.forward.

Is there anyway to adapt the Transform.lookat() to achieve this? or is there another function I should be using?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this gameObject.transform.LookAt(targetTransform,gameObject.transform.up); by doing this gameObject's y will point to target object.

Comment: Hi, I've tried that, but it just changes the world up. It doesn't change which of the vectors points at the target, its allways the vector.forward.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Nain's answer, when you want Up vector to point to target, try passing negative of forward vector i.e.

gameObject.transform.LookAt(targetTransform, -1 * gameObject.transform.forward);

this should get you the expected results, as the object is now roatated considering the up vector being the back vector.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Transform.LookAt Documentation](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.LookAt.html), we can see that second parameter is controlling worldUp. And what you want to do is, 'transform.up' pointing at forward direction. So according to Left Hand Rule in Unity Coordinate System, your forward must be pointing downward. That means negative of your `transform.forward` must be used as `WorldUp` param.

**Example:**

```
transform.LookAt(targetTransform, -transform.forward);
```

Answer (score -1):

This code uses lookDirection instead of lookPostion but you can easly calc direction from position direction = lookAtPos-lookerPos

```
//Makes the gameObject look towards "lookDirection" with customizable "lookerForwardVector"
     public static Quaternion LookAtDirection(GameObject looker, Vector3 lookAtDirection, Vector3 lookerForwardVector)
     {
         Transform inputTransform = looker.transform;
         inputTransform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(lookAtDirection); //calculating look rotation

         //Changes the LookAt alignment, like you can use "Vector3.up" vector instead of default "Vector3.forward"
         inputTransform.Rotate(GetForwardVectorAngleOffest(lookerForwardVector), Space.Self);

         return inputTransform.rotation;
     }

     static Vector3 GetForwardVectorAngleOffest(Vector3 forwardVector)
     {
         if(forwardVector == Vector3.up)
             return new Vector3(90, 0, 0);

         if (forwardVector == Vector3.right)
             return new Vector3(0, -90, 0);

         return new Vector3(0, 0, 0); ;
     }
```